# How to use findViewById() from an list-index-string . findViewById(R.id."List.get(indexnumber)")?

Tags: android

`Hello:

I have the following problem. I have an string list ironList. And I need to set alpha to many images. Such images ID's are named imageViewXX. As in the list. Bellow.

Such list will delete some components randomlly. Meaning. ironList may be decreased randomly until four "imagesViews" only. Bellow.  ( this is not the problem. The problem is about using FindviewbyId). Just highlight this. since the findviewbyId does not call from the list index.

I tried to use the following syntax but does not work. ironList.get(0). Seems is not the way to proceed.

how should I use this function properlly for this case?

This formula does not work. but. any solution? findViewById(R.id.ironList.get(0))`

```
String[] iron = {"imageView10", "imageView11", "imageView12", "imageView13", "imageView14", "imageView15", "imageView16", "imageView17", "imageView18"};
List<String> ironList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(iron));
ImageView myImageIB = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ironList.get(0));
        myImageIB.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
ImageView myImageIC = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ironList.get(1));
        myImageIC.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
ImageView myImageID = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ironList.get(2));
        myImageID.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
ImageView myImageIE = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ironList.get(3));
        myImageIE.setAlpha((float) 1.0);`
```

Comment: SetAlpha to select elements only? If so, which ones? Is it before or after the elements are deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what you are trying to do but it may help this. just change from your string array to int array!

```
  int[] iron = {R.id.yourImageView1, R.id.yourimageview2... };
ImageView myImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(iron[0]);
    myImage2 .setAlpha((float) 1.0);
ImageView myImage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(iron[1]);
    myImage3 .setAlpha((float) 1.0);
ImageView myImage4 = (ImageView) findViewById(iron[2]); ...
    myImage4.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks! for the feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

If string in iron array ("imageView10", "imageView11" etc.) is your defined ids in xml layout, your approach is not so good. If you want to `setAlpha()` to `ImageView`s then you should create list of ImageViews like that:

```
ImageView[] myImageViewList = {findViewById(R.id.yourdefinedID1), findViewById(R.id.yourdefinedID2),...};
```

And get the `ImageView` and `setAlpha()` to it.

```
myImageViewList[0].setAlpha(1f);
```

Comment: Thanks! ! You totally right! it is actually more effective. thanks!! :)

Comment: @JuanPabloZúñiga if that worked, can you please accept the answer?